# Architecture of a System using Custom Fields

Tags: sql, mongodb, postgresql, database-design, database

I am building a CRM in python.  The CRM is for a niche business where the majority of the companies have the same fields.  However, each company will have 5 or 6 custom fields.

What is the best database / architecture to use when building this?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a table as company_di; proprety_name;  proprety_value

where each company have it own custom data